# How do I add markers to streets only - Android Development

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

After plenty of searching, I haven't yet found a solution that works for me and I'm really hoping someone here could help me.  First I'll explain my problem, and then I'll mention some of the approaches I've attempted/considered so far.

Basically, I'm developing an Android app where markers randomly appear around the user's location.  The catch is, the markers need to be placed on streets only.

I've been working with Google Maps Android API V2 but I'm trying to work around using anything with "limitations" such as 'geocoding'.

I've considered using different map API's such as Nutiteq but I've had some trouble implementing them.  It would be nice to stick to Google since I've become familiar with it but I'm willing to try any suggestions you may have.

I have even considered loading up Google Maps API V3 in an html file so that I can use GDirections to load a path from one point to itself and then parse this data to Google Maps Android API V2 using JS but turns out GDirections has a limit as well.

Anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this?  Even if the solution is hacky, it's still something.

I'm fairly new to Android Development.

Comment: Your question gave me an idea for development time improvement in an app I was planning to finish. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny what you want to achieve. You don't need to load API V3 html. You can use directions api directly: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51,19&destination=51,19&sensor=false

It still has limitations, but is was like 2000 or something a day a device. And you don't want to put more than 2000 markers on single user's screen, do you?

This is easy to parse, for example with Gson.

Comment: I see, so the limitations apply to individual users, not my API key?

Comment: I wanted to write "Correct.", but this was too short for a comment.