# How can i know if my marker is on a street

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i've some marker (identified by latitude and longitude) that rappresents a cars, and i wanna know if one of this points is on the street.

There's a method for do this?

I've think that can i :

1. get the address of the combination latitude-longitude of the car
2. get the lat-lng of the address
3. compare the 2 lat-lon for verify that is the same (or nearly)

But it seems complicated and computationally expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the idea I put here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15837303/2183804

You will get a point on a street in return and then you check the distance using Location.distanceBetween. If it's less then 10 meters or so, you can assume it's on the street.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert latitude and longitude in spatial data.

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
```

You can now check the list. If the list is null, then the marker is not on a street.

GeoCoder Tutorial: http://kindohm.com/blog/2010/10/06/androidgpsgeocoding.html

Comment: I've think the same thing, but in the list there is always an address, even when set the coordinates of a lake